# Three JS animate rotation of a mesh towards specific coordinates in space

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

So I have an airplane model facing a default location(Z axis).
By clicking a button the airplane should slowly turn towards a vector with a certain rotation speed.. something similar with `model.lookAt(farAwayMesh.x, farAwayMesh.y, farAwayMesh.z)`;
but to be animated.

I've done this before in 2d but honestly I have no idea how to do this in 3d.(Not planning to use Tween.js)

I hope that anyone who encountered the same issue could support me, already spent some good hours trying.

Answer (score 0):

3D orientation interpolation is done with quaternions, refer to http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Quaternion.slerp, read [3D Math primer for graphics and game development](https://books.google.com.bo/books/about/3D_Math_Primer_for_Graphics_and_Game_Dev.html?id=TvrRBQAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y&hl=en) to learn how quaternions work